# Knock out Observable binding issue on HTML

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, observable

I have created two observables variables on Knock Out as follow:

```
 self.winImage1= ko.observable();
 self.winImage2= ko.observable();
```

And validated and stored platform based CSS for the observable variables in JS as follow:

```
self.findOperatingSystem = function (data) {

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {

    data.winImage1("window_icon_1_css");
    data.winImage2("windows_icon_2_css");
}
else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1){

    data.winImage1("mac_icon_1_css");
    data.winImage2("mac_icon_2_css");   
    }
}
```

And then tried to add the observable variables to HTML as a class as follows:

```
<div class="some_class1" data-bind="visible: $root.DeviceModel.findOperatingSystem ($parent)">

    <i data-bind="foreach: $data.winImage1()"></i>
    <i data-bind="foreach: $data.winImage2()"></i>  

</div>
```

But getting error while using foreach.
Someone, please help to identify what am doing wrong here.
Suspect using wrong data-bind!

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that foreach does not work like that. You will need an array of observables to work with it like so:

```
self.itemsArray = [ko.observable({ id: 1, name: 'image1'}), ko.observable({id:2, name:'image2'})];
self.winImages = ko.observableArray(itemsArray );



<div class="some_class1" data-bind="visible: $root.DeviceModel.findOperatingSystem($parent), foreach: winImages ">
<i data-bind="attr: { id: $data.id}"></i>
```